# OpcUa: how to monitoring almost-steady variables

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qtopcua

Ubuntu 22.04, Qt 6.4.0 with QOpcUa.
I enable the monitoring of an OpcUa variable in this way:

```
QOpcUaNode *node = // retrieve the desired node
QOpcUaMonitoringParameters params(1000);
params.setMaxKeepAliveCount(1);
params.setLifetimeCount(3);

QOpcUaNode *node = // retrieve the desired node
node->enableMonitoring(QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::Value, params);
```

In the factory we have two different type of machines (from different manufacturers).
In both we have some variables that are almost steady, it means they change their values very seldom - even once a day.

With this code I'm able to keep the connection alive for one of these machines. On the others the connection is closed by the server every few minutes - no matter the values of the parameters above - with the following reasons:

```
"Received a ServiceFault response"
"The ServiceResult has the StatusCode BadTimeout"
"Received Timeout for Publish Response"
"The ServiceResult has the StatusCode BadNoSubscription"
```

I'm [aware](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part4/v104/docs/5.13.2) the parameters should match the "speed of change" of the variables in order to optimize the publishing interval and notifications handling. I also tried 1000 and 3000 with just a little change in the behavior (the connection survived a little longer, but still in the order of minutes).

I also tried to add a poll of a variable every few second with the hope of keeping the connection open. Instead the server closes the connection anyway - my guess is that the monitor handling has the precedence.

Please note that if I enable the monitoring for the variables that change the value constantly the connection does **not** drop at all.

I have two simple questions:

1. what are the right settings to monitor a *steady* variable?
2. should not the server still push a notification even if the variable has *not* changed to keep alive the connection?

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if I can do anything on my side or it is the server that does not handle the connection correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't anything to do with the subscription values, if they change or not. You have to do other requests like read, write to keep a session alive.
My tipp just read a variable every 10 seconds or so. A possible variable is the server status.

Comment: I should add this in the question. I've already tried to manually poll a variable, but this does not affect the behavior. I'm pretty sure it depends from the monitoring settings since if I monitor only variables that continue to change the value the connection never drops.

Comment: Question updated, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You could add the the Server_ServerStatus_CurrentTime (i=2258) to your subscription. This value will change every second, so this could keep the subscription alive.

Comment: Yeah, your last hint did the trick, apparently. It seems to me a workaround, but since this morning I didn't catch a single disconnection!